# Getting an error Error in executeUpdate, Table has no partition for value from column_list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an error "Error in executeUpdate, Table has no partition for value from column_list"

I have not used SQL in years.
This is the insert

```
INSERT INTO messages
        (RunId, RunStart, RunFinish, ChannelId, StartMessageId, 
        FinishMessageId, Status, Error, NoOfMessages, NoOfFinalMessages, 
        NoOfMediaFiles, NoOfNewChannels) 
VALUES ('635c8dd3-f476-49a1-8993-570dccb914e9', '2021-11-15 10:43:08.193', 
        '2021-11-15 10:43:08.211', 1, 1, 100, 'Success', null, 100, 50, 25, 5)
```

Reading the error, I think its treating one of the params as a list, am I right.

Comment: Look at the schema for that table, or show us! it has been partitioned and one of the columns in this INSERT breaks the partition rules

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Thank you I will look at the schema for the table,